# How to extract a value from a key/value pair in NSDictionary (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, keyvaluepair

When debugging in XCode, the debugger is telling me that the NSDictionary object contains 1 key/value pair. When the debug console prints the description of the key/value pair is shows:

```
Printing description of testdictionary:
{
    "Unknown (<1809>)" = <000000ff>;
}
```

I want to extract both the <1809> and the <000000ff>. I have tried both the valueForKey and objectforKey methods as described elsewhere on this site. But I think I am having difficulty understanding what is the key and what is the value here.

For example, is `"Unknown (<1809>)"` the key? Or is `"<1809>"` the key? Or is `1809` the key?

---

Thanks Tim for the reply.

The NSDictionary comes from the CoreBluetoothFramework the didDiscoverPeripheral: method is called and passes advertising data into an NSDictionary called "advertisementData".

This dictionary contains all sorts of stuff like the advertising channel and device name. However, I am trying to extract just the advertising data from "advertisementData". I used the key provided by corebluetooth "CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey" like this:

```
NSData* information;
information = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey];
```

I was declaring "information" as an NSDictionary* object before. But changed it to NSData* after some more reading on Apples documentation. The result is the same. The debugger says that it contains a key/value pair as follows:

```
"Unknown (<1809>)" = <000000ff>;
```

Thanks again.

Nik

Comment: Where did that `NSDictionary` come from?

Comment: dasblinkenlight. That's a good question, I updated the post to give some more background on where the NSDictionary comes from.

Comment: Try `id val = [testdictionary objectForKey:@"Unknown (<1809>)"]`, it should give you the object stored in the dictionary.

Comment: dasblinkenlight. Unfortunately that just give "val" a <nil> value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do not know the keys that are present in the dictionary, for example, because the key-value pairs come from an external source, you can use `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` method to go through all key-value pairs present in the dictionary:

```
[testdictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock::^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"The key is %@", key);
    NSLog(@"The value is %@", object);
}];
```

Comment: dasblinkenlight. That's very helpful thanks. From this, it confirms the keys and objects as follows: 2013-09-21 08:09:53.504 cB-OLP425[1091:60b] The key is Unknown (<1809>)
2013-09-21 08:09:53.506 cB-OLP425[1091:60b] The value is <000000ff>

Comment: @NikTheGreek You can set a breakpoint in the debugger, and examine the type of the key. It does not look like it`s `NSString`.

Comment: dasblinkenlight. The dubugger says the object is of type _NSInlineData*. That is interesting since its not what I was expecting according to Apple'd documentation.

Comment: @NikTheGreek Perfect! You may want to ask a separate question explaining what you did, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: dasblinkenlight. That's a good idea. Thank you for the help! Nik

Comment: dasblinkenlight. It is a strange one. The NSInlineData type is not documented anywhere. Google returns 0 results, even. I'll mark this one as finished and come back with some more specifics. Thanks again. Nik

Comment: _NSInlineData is one of the many specialized immutable NSData subclasses. Treat it just like NSData.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this before so this is nothing more than an educated guess:

The dictionary may have been casted from `CFDictionaryRef`, in which case both the key and value are `const void *` (instead of `NSObject`). The key might have been some Core Foundation type holding a file descriptor (hence 1809). The value could be a pointer (or an integer casted to a "pointer": `(void *)32`).

You should try and find out where the dictionary originates from, because it's the only thing that's going to give you any valuable information.

---

*Update:* the docs state that the value of `CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey` is a dictionary. The keys are `CBUUID` objects, representing `CBService` UUIDs and the values are `NSData` objects. [(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManagerDelegate_Protocol/translated_content/CBCentralManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CBCentralManagerDelegate/centralManagerDidUpdateState%3a)

Comment: Thanks Tim, I updated my post above with some more information about where the NSDictionary comes from.

Comment: Yes to me that means "Unknown (<1809>)" is the CBService UUID and <000000ff> is the NSData object. However, extracting the NSData object  is appearing problematic using the method that dasblinkenlight suggested above.